# DHCP is not working

Tags: boot, pxe, tftp, dhcpd

I am using 14.04 and installed `isc-dhcp-server` in my Ubuntu. Here is my DHCP configuration:

```
INTERFACES="eth0"

allow booting;
allow bootp;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range dynamic-bootp 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.200;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    filename "/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0";
}
```

When I check this:

```
ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ dhcpd -t /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf: interface name too long (is 20)
```

And I tried to boot in PXE in remote system I failed. How to solve this?

```
PXE-E51: No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received.

PXE-M0F: Exiting Broadcom ROM.
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.9
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 5
```

`ifconfig` details:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:a4:ec:87  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:a4:ec:87  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:380900 (380.9 KB)  TX bytes:380900 (380.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:de:2b:e2:94:c6  
          inet addr:192.168.43.9  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76de:2bff:fee2:94c6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13954 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3537434 (3.5 MB)  TX bytes:1880208 (1.8 MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DHCP server displays an error and restarts after launching network, open the `interfaces` file using your preferred text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then enter the following lines to your liking:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.*
    network 192.168.1.**
    netmask 255.255.255 
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    up service isc-dhcp-server restart
    auto eth0
```

Now restart your system with:

```
sudo reboot
```

Your DHCP server should now be functional. To test if DHCP is working run the `dhclient` command.

Comment: sorry i cannot understand french. but i understood a little bit.

Comment: I tried what you have said but now my total eth0 is not working.

Comment: In english it's better ;-) Open a terminal on the server and run "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog". Then start up a client and see what gets logged during the DHCP exchange. What do you see?

I assume there's nothing else on your network providing DHCP services, right? Like a router perhaps?

Comment: yes i am trying with two laptops thats it.

Comment: I have a ubuntu guest installed in kvm. I have configured br0 interface. and eth0 wlan0 i have. but when i connected the lan its not showing the eth0 connection.

Comment: i will post the more info of my network connections.

Comment: @Yolateng0 It seems like you can speak English fluently enough, please from now on write in English only because this site is in English. Michael Lindman had to translate your post and I had to check his translation. Not a big deal, but if you can speak English well that's just a waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf


default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.254;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
option domain-name "***********";
option ntp-servers 192.168.1.254;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
  range 192.168.1.110 192.168.1.200;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in a little more details what is and how it solves the issues?

Comment: ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ sudo dhcpd -t /etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf
/etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf: interface name too long (is 19)

Comment: Hi, have you test your interfaces? try in terminal : dhclient eth0 or dhclient eth1. What is the result?

Comment: Once done , check your configuration file :

dhcpd -t /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

Specify the interface on which IP addresses will be assigned .

nano / etc / default / isc- dhcp-server

At line : INTERFACES = "" , the one or interfaces ( comma separated ) to listen.

Home that will :

INTERFACES = " eth0"

Then restart the dhcp server

/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart

If the DHCP server displays an error

It will restart after the launch of networking.

nano / etc / network / interfaces

Comment: "ethernetworks device not managed ubuntu" this error i have

Comment: Good news, the idea whether that error was based. you have an explanation for this link: http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/11/25/how-to-fix-wired-network-interface-device-not-managed-error/